# How do you update an existing date to a random date in a range?

Tags: datetime, random

In one of my tables I have **datetime** field in which the data in the table column is populated with something like "`2016-01-07 01:33:00`".

What I want to do is change **ONLY** the date to a **random date** within a range (`ie: 2016-02-01 thru 2016-02-28`) without changing the time. The end result might be "`2016-02-13 01:33:00`".

What **mysql command** string would accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE someTable SET someDate = DATE_ADD(
    someDate,
    INTERVAL
        DATEDIFF(rangeStart, someDate) +
        ROUND(RAND()*DATEDIFF(rangeEnd, rangeStart))
    DAY
);
```

where `someTable.someDate` is your existing data, and `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd` are the boundaries of your target date range.

Here you take the initial date, add enough days to it to reach the range start, and then further add a random number of days no greater than the number of days in your target range.

Answer (score 0):

In MsSQL it could be:

> select dateadd(day,cast((RAND() * 30) as int),getdate())

Substitute getdate() with your input date.
(RAND() * 30) is used to randomly generate a number of days up to 30.